# Conditionally adding buttons to jQueryUI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-dialog

Based on a given condition, I would like to have either one or two buttons on a jQueryUI Dialog.

The condition is defined within the `DIV` element, by setting data-includeUploadButton to either 0 or 1.

I suppose I can create a buttons array in the open method, and then use `buttons:buttons`.

Or maybe easier to read, is it possible to put the conditional directly when creating the object notation array?

Or maybe some other way?  I would rather not have a bunch of global variables floating around.

Thanks!

```
<div id="dialog-conditional" title="dialog-conditional" data-includeUploadButton="1"></div>

$("#dialog-conditional").dialog({
    //....
    open        : function() {
        var includeUploadButton=$(this).data('includeUploadButton');
    },
    buttons     : [
        {text    : 'UPLOAD',"class"  : 'green'},
        {text    : 'CLOSE',click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}}
    ]    
});
```

Comment: Actually, it will not work to create the buttons array in the open method.

Comment: I don't like how I did it, but at least it works.  I always include both buttons in the buttons array, but hide/show the second button in the open method based on data-includeUploadButton.  If anyone has a better way, please advise.  Thans